# Guidelines for "rounded" icon in Android 7.1

Tags: android, material-design, android-icons, android-7.1-nougat

Android 7.1 now supports [Round Icon Resources](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html#circular-icons).

Are there any "hard" specifications/requirements for the rounded icon?

So far, I have only seen round icons with a white background, is that mandatory?

It would be great to have some information on the padding of the circle, for example.